# How can I start over from middle of the program if the input goes wrong

Tags: python

```
# nested loop # finding the large number.
system = 1
while system:
    number1 = input('1st value: ')
    try:
        int(number1)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(number1)
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: This is not a Number. Try again')
            break
    number2 = input('2nd value: ')
    try:
        int(number2)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(number2)
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: This is not a Number. Try again')
            break
    number3 = input('3rd value: ')
    try:
        int(number3)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(number3)
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: This is not a Number. Try again')
            break
    number4 = input('4th value: ')
    try:
        int(number4)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(number4)
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: This is not a Number. Try again')
            break
    list = [float(number1), float(number2), float(number3), float(number4)]
    large_number = list[0]
    total = 0
    small_number = list[0]
    # we assumed that the largest number is the first one on the "list" variable
    for line_value in list:
        if line_value > large_number:
            large_number = line_value
    print(f'the largest number of the list is:{large_number}')

    for line_value in list:
        if line_value < small_number:
            small_number = line_value
    print(f'the smallest number is: {small_number}')

    for line_value in list:
        total += line_value
    print(f'and the sum is: {total}')
    break
```

I was practicing and it came here. Now I want to restart everything following by a error massage when ever the user enters a character other then number. Now the error massage is showing, but as I failed to restart it after the massage I just broke the loop.. please help me. I am just 3 days old in any type of coding.

Comment: use `continue` and add [mcve] not the whole code which distracts the users.

Comment: Use `max`, `min` and `sum` to find maximum, minimum, and summation, respectively, of list.

Comment: I was practicing "for loop". that is why I was not using "max", "min" and "sum". but my question was how to loop back if user input a value other then number.

Answer (score 0):

You should never repeat code, what you can do is write a function which gets the number for you:

```
def get_number(x):                          
    n = input (f"Enter the {x} value: ")
    try: return float(n)
    except ValueError: return get_number(x) #this will call the function each time the error would be raised


while True:                   #You can just use while True: instead of declaring a variable just for that
    number1 = get_number("1st")
    number2 = get_number("2nd")
    number3 = get_number("3rd")
    number4 = get_number("4th")
    list = [number1, number2, number3, number4] #From here on the code stays unchanged
```

Comment: Thank you very much. exactly what I was looking for. I am in day 3 of my python learning (this is my introduction to coding. :D) and hadn't started to work with function. thanks again for your help, and I got the idea.